# How to compress files before they are saved?

Tags: file, compression, storage

I want to do a free photo sharing website and wanted to know what is the best way to lower storage costs? Obviously, there is no clear answer, i am aware of that much.  The cheapest i know is $0.15/GB.  But is there something else that i can do programming wise to maybe compress files or something?

Answer (score 1):

Images are often already compressed so you won't save here. What you can and should do is have a global image storage and avoid duplicates in it. The reason is that people often upload the same file several times (a group photo can be uploaded by all members of the group).

This is how its done:

- you have a global storage of images, where each image file has a
  reference counter
- when the user uploads some file, you calculate its hash and see if you have files of the same size with the same hash in your image storage. If you do, you increment a reference
  counter for the file and associate user upload with existing file by storing a link to existing file in records, associated with the user.
- when the user deletes "his" file, you remove the link and decrement the reference counter. If the counter reaches zero, you delete the file.
- if your storage allows file editing, you will need to use copy-on-write, i.e. make a copy of the file when it's modified by the user.